# Fixed nav under a relative div

Tags: less

I have a relative div above a fixed one which acts like a navigation bar.

I want to be able to scroll past the relative div before the fixed div starts having to scroll [here](http://jasonglover.co.uk) is my website.

as you can see from just scrolling on the site the sidebar doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JavaScript to detect the scroll position of the window and then change the CSS to start scrolling like a fixed div.

Another tip, the the fixed div which contains your projects on the home page lays over your footer when you scroll to the bottom.
Use JavaScript to detect if the user is at the bottom of the page or not and then set the CSS of it to have a margin from the bottom of the page.

Hope I helped.

Comment: It's not my footer that's the problem although i do realize that's a problem. thanks I'll consider that if i can't find a css solution

Comment: You can use the same way to fix the problem with your header

Comment: and I personally think that when you put the word "Projects" into the fixed div it will look a lot nicer

Comment: thanks, I'll try and find some information on this but I am afraid I don't know any javascript myself

Comment: Coulc anyone give me an example please?

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm only a student